# Does Jersey 2.x API have one function that can execute flexible REST verbs (GET, POST)

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I'm in the middle of upgrading a bunch of test harness Groovy(Java) to execute against the Jersey 2.x Client (javax.ws.rs.client.Client), upgrading it from 1.x. I'll likely stumble upon the feature soon but can't see if for the changes I'm making right now. Have been poring through [the API](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.22/jersey/javax/ws/rs/client/SyncInvoker.html#put(javax.ws.rs.client.Entity)) looking for an answer to my question.

The new API seems to only permit strict fluent interface verbs e.g.

```
Response response = invocationBuilder.get();
```

The old 1.x code allowed a parameter that defines the method type using a string parameter called *method*:

```scala
def response = userServiceContext.target()
                 .path("/$path")
                 .method(method, ClientResponse.class)
```

Annoyingly strict new code displaying a 'put' call (examples):

```
WebTarget resourceTarget = jerseyClient().target("/$path")
Invocation invocation = resourceTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_ATOM_XML)
                          .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_ATOM_XML)
                          .put(ClientResponse.class, entry)
return invocation.submit()
```

For convenience sake [asking too much? :) ] could someone point me to an out of the box method that does the same thing in 2.x? I've been digging around the API and I'm finding this an annoying [pebble](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/72/d8/49/72d84979b9af73bf4dc8170df53ef17f.jpg). Bonus points if you explain why that flexibility doesn't exist in the new API (without sass). **Apologies in advance to questions like *what have you done* or *why don't you try it and see!??***

Comment: Have you actually looked at the complete javadoc that [you linked to](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.22/jersey/javax/ws/rs/client/SyncInvoker.html#put(javax.ws.rs.client.Entity))? Scroll around. I'm sure you'll find something ;-)

Comment: If I understand you question correctly, you are just looking for the `method` method, which there is one. Is there something else you were looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can do something like `resourceTarget.request().build(method)...` to do what you are looking for. Check out the docs for the `build(String method)` and `build(String method, Entity<?> entity)` methods [here](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.22/jersey/javax/ws/rs/client/Invocation.Builder.html#build(java.lang.String)).